# > Android resource linking failed ERROR:: AAPT: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

i am trying to run my new flutter project in visual studio code, but i am getting this kind of problem in my debug console, is there any way to solve it?

I am getting this while trying to run build in debug mode

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:: AAPT: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.
```